# rename all files after extension

Tags: linux, shell

Is it possible to write a script to rename all files after the extension?

Example in the folder, there are :

```
hello.txt-123ahr
bye.txt-56athe
test.txt-98hg12
```

I want the output:

```
hello.txt
bye.txt
test.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to remove everything from the dash forwards, you can use Parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.txt-* ; do
    mv "$file" "${file%-*}"
done
```

Where `${file%-*}` means "remove from `$file` everytning from the last dash". If you want to start from the first dash, use `%%`.

Note that you might overwrite some files if their leading parts are equivalent, e.g. `hello.txt-123abc` and `hello.txt-456xyz`.